Magento 2 Your payment could not be taken. Please try again or use a different payment method. Declined Trace:
Preconditions and environment
Upgrade Magento version from 2.4.5-p1 to 2.4.6-p3
Magento version 2.4.6-p3
Steps to reproduce
1 - In production environment Place order with braintree creditcard or braintree Paypal
2 - We are getting an error of "Exception message: Your payment could not be taken. Please try again or use a different payment method. Declined Trace:" on magento logs
3 - This issue is only coming for few customers
4 - 3D Secure Verification is enabled
5 - Always request 3DS is enabled
Expected result
Order should be placed successfully.
Actual result
We are getting an error of "Exception message: Your payment could not be taken. Please try again or use a different payment method. Declined Trace:" on magento logs
On Braintree portal it is showing -
Status Processor Declined
Processor Response Text Declined(2046)
Additional Processor Response 2046: PAYER_ACTION_REQUIRED

Have you configured the payment details again?

@DhirenVasoya it was already configured, we just upgrade magento version from 2.4.5-p1 to 2.4.6-p3 so admin settings details have same and it is coming for few customers.

This isn't an issue originating from your end. The error code (2046) from Braintree, indicating a declined transaction, suggests that the problem lies with "The customer's bank being unwilling to accept the transaction."
Reference Link : https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/articles/control-panel/transactions/declines


we just upgraded the version from 2.4.5-p1 to 2.4.6-p3, it may be possible because of customers fill wrong information at checkout ?
